# Take html that was saved as TEXT to database and send back to browser?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

So I am trying to build a kind of blog site. Users can save blogs via a wysiwyg and that gets save to the database as a text string. I've run into a problem though.
When I dump that back to the browser it is all escaped and rendered as a giant string. In order to cicumvent this I did this:

```
renderContent = () => {
  if (this.props.content_type === "blog") {
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let title = parser.parseFromString(this.props.title, "text/html");
    let decoded_title = title.body.textContent;

    let content = parser.parseFromString(this.props.content, "text/html");
    let decoded_content = content.body.textContent;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <img src={this.props.hero_image} alt="hero image" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.props.handleClose}>Back</button>
        </div>
        <div>{decoded_title}</div>
        <div>{decoded_content}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

My problem is that this seems to render any lines breaks gone, all links gone, and an image that was in content is now just not showing up at all.

The original content before being decoded looks like this:

```
<p>
  <img
    src="https://img.aws.livestrongcdn.com/ls-article-image-673/s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/contentlab.studiod/getty/a6e0848c23aa4d46820e944e24c4b7f2.jpg"
    alt="Your dog wants to help when you're upset, and here's proof"
  />
</p>
<section class="subsection article__section__step article_module_section">
  <p class="article-section__content" data-dmc="section">
    Can dogs understand when we are distressed and respond accordingly?
    According to new research, man&rsquo;s best friend not only notices when
    you (or other humans) are upset, but will actually adapt their behavior as
    a result. What a good boy!
  </p>
  <p class="article-section__content" data-dmc="section">
    The study, published in the journal&nbsp;
    <a
      class="markdown-anchor"
      href="https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2Fs13420-018-0332-3"
      target="_blank"
      rel="nofollow noopener"
    >
      Learning &amp; Behavior
    </a>
    , found that canines were faster to respond to humans who sounded upset
    versus humans who sounded calm.
  </p>
  <p class="article-section__content" data-dmc="section">
    &ldquo;It&rsquo;s really cool for us to know that dogs are so sensitive to
    human emotional states,&rdquo; Emily Sanford, a graduate student in
    psychological and brain sciences at Johns Hopkins University and co-author
    of the study, explained to&nbsp;
  </p>
</section>
```

Is there a way I can do this on my node side before ever reaching the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to put it into dangerouslySetInnerHTML props:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.title}}/>
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.content}}/>
```

However, it will be dangerous because your site will face XSS vulnerable or such. So make sure to make your content safe first. I recommend using `sanitize-html` to allow certain tags, and attrs only.

```
const cleanTitle = sanitizeHtml(this.props.title, {
  allowedTags: [ 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a' ],
  allowedAttributes: {
    'a': [ 'href' ]
  },
  allowedIframeHostnames: ['www.youtube.com']
});
```

https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html

Comment: Thank you. Blogs can only be entered by a high level user like an admin, but I'll still look into that sanitize package as you never know what people are going to do.

Comment: That's true. Even your editor doesn't mean to do something harm. When they copy content from other source and don't notice, there might be problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render HTML from a string.

**Example**

```js
const content = `
<p>
  <img
    src="https://img.aws.livestrongcdn.com/ls-article-image-673/s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/contentlab.studiod/getty/a6e0848c23aa4d46820e944e24c4b7f2.jpg"
    alt="Your dog wants to help when you're upset, and here's proof"
  />
</p>
<section class="subsection article__section__step article_module_section">
  <p class="article-section__content" data-dmc="section">
    Can dogs understand when we are distressed and respond accordingly?
    According to new research, man&rsquo;s best friend not only notices when
    you (or other humans) are upset, but will actually adapt their behavior as
    a result. What a good boy!
  </p>
  <p class="article-section__content" data-dmc="section">
    The study, published in the journal&nbsp;
    <a
      class="markdown-anchor"
      href="https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2Fs13420-018-0332-3"
      target="_blank"
      rel="nofollow noopener"
    >
      Learning &amp; Behavior
    </a>
    , found that canines were faster to respond to humans who sounded upset
    versus humans who sounded calm.
  </p>
  <p class="article-section__content" data-dmc="section">
    &ldquo;It&rsquo;s really cool for us to know that dogs are so sensitive to
    human emotional states,&rdquo; Emily Sanford, a graduate student in
    psychological and brain sciences at Johns Hopkins University and co-author
    of the study, explained to&nbsp;
  </p>
</section>
`

function App() {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content}} />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```